# NFT2.0 from coding point of view

Tags: solidity, nft

Can anyone explain NFT2.0 from a coding(Solidity) point of view? or introduce a source.

Comment: NFT 2.0 is mostly a marketing thing now. There are a few improvement proposals https://eips.ethereum.org/all for NFTs, but there's no concrete proposal named like that. Other "blockchains" have named NTF 2.0 to different proposals but nothing standard.